# Configure AWS SSO with Auth0 as IDP

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, saml

I am trying to configure “AWS SSO”'s to work with Auth0 as an External Identity Provider. I have made is to the point where I am getting the auth0 login as success but AWS throws me an error.

error I get after logging in via auth0:
[image: error I get after logging in via auth0]

Steps I have taken

Goto Auth0 Application > Addon > SAML2 Web App
Application Callback URL : {{ AWS SSO ACS URL}}
Settings

```
{
    "audience": "{{ AWS SSO Sign-in URL}}",
    "destination": "{{ AWS SSO issuer URL}}",
    "mappings": {
        "email": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress",
        "name": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"
    },
    "signResponse": false,
    "createUpnClaim": false,
    "passthroughClaimsWithNoMapping": false,
    "mapUnknownClaimsAsIs": false,
    "mapIdentities": true,
    "nameIdentifierFormat": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress",
    "nameIdentifierProbes": [
        "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"
    ]
}
```

Saml response : https://gist.github.com/Rohithzr/9bf1bc854e8a3ad79e68e1d41fbc7154
Can anyone help me as I am not really getting any logs to debug from AWS

Answer (score 0):

Good news, I think I just figured this out!

I followed a [different guide to configure Okta with AWS SSO](https://controltower.aws-management.tools/infrastructure/sso/okta_sso/) and then compared some of the differences between that and the [Auth0 guide](https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws/sso?_ga=2.129188300.1721885674.1589483049-294586808.1589483049). I made three changes and got this working with Auth0 + AWS SSO.

```
{
  "audience": "{{AWS SSO issuer URL}}",
  "destination": "{{AWS SSO ACS URL}}",
  "mappings": {
    "email": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress",
    "name": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"
  },
  "createUpnClaim": true,
  "passthroughClaimsWithNoMapping": false,
  "mapUnknownClaimsAsIs": false,
  "mapIdentities": false,
  "nameIdentifierFormat": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress",
  "nameIdentifierProbes": [
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"
  ]
}
```

The three key changes were:

1. the **audience** should be the AWS SSO issuer URL, not the sign-in URL
2. the **destination** should be the AWS SSO ACS URL, not the issuer URL
3. the **nameIdentifierFormat** should be `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress` (this is the same value you have... I'm only calling it out because the [Auth0 AWS SSO guide](https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws/sso?_ga=2.129188300.1721885674.1589483049-294586808.1589483049) says `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent`, which doesn't seem to work; sharing in case others read this post).